# Which search parameters do I need to get the 'Conspiracy Theorist' achievement?

Tags: mass-effect-3, achievements

I'm early on in the Mass Effect 3 DLC 'Leviathan' and I have been asked to search a lab. I have found all of the clues and I'm trying to get the achievement 'Conspiracy Theorist':

> **Conspiracy Theorist**:
>   Use clues to pinpoint the exact location of an objective.

Which search parameters do I have to activate in order to get this achievement?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To get the 'conspiracy theorist' achievement you need to use the following search parameters:

- Locations with Reaper Activity (purple)
- Locations with Creature Sightings (red)
- Locations with Element Zero Deposits (orange)

[image: activated search parameters]